# How to parse input String and search in MongoDB, "a*","*a*","*a","a, b","a..b"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a web app (JS, NodeJS, MongoDB, Meteor) and want to add a search function for my order list. When searching by order number (string):

If input is

- `a*`, return order numbers that begin with `a`, like a001
- `*a`, return order numbers that end with `a`, like x00a
- `*a*`,return order numbers that have an `a` in the middle, like 100a01
- `a, b`, return order numbers are `a` or `b`
- `a..b`, return order numbers from `a` to `b` (like, 50001..50005)

As a new programmer, I have no idea how to do it. Shall i just parse it to each branch and convert the query to a regular expression? 
Any JS or Mongo regex code for example? Any better way to do it? Is there any package to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at Mongoose?

Comment: First things first: Read up on what indexes are; especially the third example is a real killer for performance. The other examples will greatly benefit from correct indexes.

Comment: thanks @Edwin, i use Meteor so only mongo

Answer (score 1):

mongodb supports finding records with regexes. See [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). For example,

```
db.orders.find( { order_id: { $regex: /a*/ } } )
```